# How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone, svn-checkout

**Problem**

How do you create a shallow copy with git-svn from a Subversion repository, e.g. how do you pull only the last three revisions?

The `git clone` command can get the last n revisions from a Git repository if you use the option `--depth`, i.e. you get a shallow copy of the repository. Example:

```
git clone --depth 3 git://some/repo myshallowcopyrepo
```

Is there a similar option for git-svn?

**My discoveries so far**

So far I've only found the `-rN` option where `N` is the revision to pull. Example:

```
git svn clone -rN svn://some/repo
```

According to the documentation there is the possibility to use `-r$REVNUMBER:HEAD`. I tried the following to get the last 3 revisions which returned an error message.

```
$ git svn clone --prefix=svn/ -s -rHEAD~3:HEAD http://some/svn/repo .
revision argument: HEAD~3:HEAD not understood by git-svn
```

So I replaced `HEAD~3` with the actual number of the third but last revision 534. That worked, but that requires me to first figure out the revision number of the third but last commit.

```
$ git svn clone --prefix=svn/ -s -r534:HEAD http://some/svn/repo .
```

**Documentation**

[git-clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

[git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

Comment: Answering my own question:
`-s is for --stdlayout which presumes the svn recommended layout for tags, trunk, and branches.`
(but didn't work for me)

Comment: How hard would it be to implement `--depth` for `git svn`, since the support is already there.  And it already has to find out the latest rev from the server?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You've already discovered the simplest way to specify a shallow clone in Git-SVN, by specifying the SVN revision number that you want to start your clone at  ( `-r$REV:HEAD`).

For example: `git svn clone -s -r1450:HEAD some/svn/repo`

Git's data structure is based on pointers in a directed acyclic graph (DAG), which makes it trivial to walk back `n` commits.  But in SVN ( and therefore in Git-SVN) you will have to find  the revision number yourself.

Comment: what if I'd like to continue cloning the earlier revision in the future, is it possible?

Comment: @Zennichimaro: You can do that by adding another `git-svn` remote pointing at the same place and using `git-svn fetch` to get more of the tree.  At that point you have to use `git filter-branch` to reparent the old (partial) tree onto the right branch.

Comment: Paul is there any way for me to get the latest revisions by performing Incremental Migration from SVN to Git
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161646/incremental-migration-from-svn-to-git)

Comment: SVN uses consecutive integers to identify revisions, making it even more trivial to walk back `n` commits ...

Comment: I think there is a space missing after -r. For e.g. git svn clone -r 1133:HEAD some/svn/repo

Answer (score 96):

I find myself using the following often to get a limited number of revisions out of our huge subversion tree (we're soon reaching svn revision 35000).

```
# checkout a specific revision
git svn clone -r N svn://some/repo/branch/some-branch
# enter it and get all commits since revision 'N'
cd some-branch
git svn rebase
```

And a good way to find out where a branch started is to do a `svn log` it and find the first one on the branch (the last one listed when doing):

```
svn log --stop-on-copy svn://some/repo/branch/some-branch
```

So far I have not really found the hassle worth it in tracking all branches. It takes too much time to clone and svn and git don't work together as good as I would like.    I tend to create patch files and apply them on the git clone of another svn branch.

Comment: +1 from me - helped me get round an error 128 issue I was having cloning an entire svn repo

Comment: the svn log command was exactly what I was looking for! thanks

Comment: Repos I work with have non-standard branching and layout, so I generally create a local Git repo for each SVN branch, and then `cherry-pick`/`rebase` between those. Commit takes an extra step (`push`, then `dcommit` from remote repo), but I think it's worth the tradeoff.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, might be quicker just cloning specific tags/branches as you say :)

Answer (score 45):

*... 7 years later, in the desert, a tumbleweed blows by ...*

I wasn't satisfied with the accepted answer so I created some scripts to do this for you [available on Github](https://github.com/jonathancone/svn-utils).  These should help anyone who wants to use `git svn clone` but doesn't want to clone the entire repository and doesn't want to hunt for a specific revision to clone from in the middle of the history (maybe you're cloning a bunch of repos).  Here we can just clone the last N revisions:

**Use `git svn clone` to clone the last 50 revisions**

```
# -u    The SVN URL to clone
# -l    The limit of revisions
# -o    The output directory

./git-svn-cloneback.sh -u https://server/project/trunk -l 50 -o myproj --authors-file=svn-authors.txt
```

**Find the previous N revision from an SVN repo**

```
# -u    The SVN URL to clone
# -l    The limit of revisions

./svn-lookback.sh -u https://server/project/trunk -l 5
```

Comment: Will give this a crack, our repo has about 170,000 revisions and it's taking waaaay too long to do a single project, and i have over 10 specific projects in the repo to do :| Considering just doing 3-4 years of history only.

Comment: I forked Jonathan's idea, made some improvements, and removed the dependency on Python, available here: https://github.com/jstine35/git-svn-cloneback

Answer (score 1):

[image]

tried with tortoisegit tool from SVN repository option, its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the error several times
"revision argument: :HEAD not understood by git-svn"

it works by increasing the number of revision limits

for example 100 instead of 50

> ./git-svn-cloneback.sh -u https://server/project/trunk -l 100 -o
> myproj --authors-file=svn-authors.txt