# Git Svn Fetch More Revisions

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using git-svn for our svn repository. However, the repo is huge, so I first checked out the project like so:

```
git svn clone svn://svn.server.com/project -s -r 12000:HEAD
```

So, now I have only revisions 12000 to the current revision. I would like to checkout some more revisions, but the following does nothing:

```
git svn fetch -r 11000:HEAD
```

Is there a way to fetch older revisions?

Comment: Could it be that revision 11000 is not a parent of the current HEAD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is really supported, doing so would rebase the entire repository which would generally be considered a bad thing. (Although pure git is more than happy to let you shoot yourself in the foot by doing this) I don't see a way to do this, even after fiddling with the data in .git/svn. You can checkout older revisions of branches and tags you haven't retrieved, but once you retrieve a branch, you can't go back and grab even more history.

I waited 6 hours for a 50k revision repo to clone, so I know your pain. If you really want that much history, I suggest just letting it run overnight and grab the entire thing.

Comment: My project's trunk has over 600,000 revisions and I have not been able to clone it even after 15 hours. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554222/git-svn-clone-how-to-defer-fetch-of-revision-history) has an answer: basically, you must not start with clone, but init and fetch.  Did not try it myself (yet)...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert enough in git and git-svn to flesh this out fully, but you *should* be able to `git svn clone` your svn into a new repo, add that repo as a remote and fetch it from your starting repo, and then add a graft point between the first commit in the old repo (`r12000`) and the *parent* of `r12000` in the new repo. That will fuse the two pieces of history together. Then again, there might need to be some more patching-up to keep git-svn operating correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I use --fetch-all "svn-git fetch --all"

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn