# Import a svn repo to git from a given point in time

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

What can I do to import a SVN repository into git but only from a (known) revision number and onwards?

I've tried with:

```
git svn clone --authors-file=/home/ubuntu/svn-git-users.lst --revision=4151 -T trunk -b branch -t tags file://`pwd`/../svn-server-sync/MyRepo MyRepo
```

But it fails with:

> r4151 = e80c7c5923700d6c7594c91f172779af63a8511b (refs/remotes/snapshots)
>   fatal: refs/remotes/trunk: not a valid SHA1

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository help? that is: `-r 4151`, instead of `-r=4151`

Comment: @VonC Thanks, it looks like that's my problem. I've tried -r4151:HEAD and, at least for the moment, it's running. My repo is several GB size so it will take a while... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, it seems it might be a syntax issue:

```
-r4151,
```

instead of `-r=4151` (no 'equal' sign needed).
The question [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository) provides some good examples.

The OP reports trying `-r4151:HEAD`, which for now is importing the SVN repo.