# Using git svn can I import to git repository last 100 revisions?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I am trying to clone big svn repository to my git repository.
The problem is that rep. is too big and svn clone works too slow.
Is there way to clone only last N revisions?

Something like that:

```
git svn clone http://svn/svn/test . (from 200 to 400 revision)
```

or maybe something like that:

```
git svn fetch (20,30,40-50 revisions)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were a git repo, you could

```
git svn clone (url) --depth (N)
```

But it is non-trivial in SVN to find the revision number of "N revisions back", unlike in Git.

So, you have to specify the revision number of the SVN yourself.

Alex has provided the right syntax.

```
git svn clone -s -r534:HEAD http://some/svn/repo
```

But it is easier on your head to remember and do the following:

```
# checkout a specific revision
git svn clone -r N svn://some/repo/branch/some-branch
# enter it and get all commits since revision 'N'
cd some-branch
git svn rebase
```

Comment: Can i after it add earlier rivisions to my rep.? (if repository already exists)

Comment: In this case can i have all svn branches in my git repository?

Comment: Astronavigator, Yes. A simpler approach is to use a "-s" switch which will map your svn branches into git branches. But that is really a different question.

Comment: Can i after it add earlier rivisions to my rep.? How to do that?

Comment: Why the -s switch?

Answer (score 2):

Specify the SVN revision number that you want to start your clone at with the `-r` switch.  `-r$REV:HEAD`.

Something like this:

```
 git svn clone --prefix=svn/ -s -r$REV:HEAD path/to/repo
```

Where `$REV` is the revision number you wish to start the clone at.