# Subversion analog of gitk or hgk

Tags: svn, gitk

I know, that I can use gitk for viewing commit history of git-based repository, I also now that I can use hgk for the same purpose, while using Mercurial.
I need something like this for Subversion. I'm using Ubuntu, so it has to work on Linux-based OS. I know, that there is [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), which allows me to do what I need, but I want a very-very simple gui-client, which allows to view history of commits and merges - nothing more.
Can anybody show me such tool?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468406/svn-log-diff-frontend-like-gitk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use Gnome? There's a Subversion plugin into Nautilus (whoops! Looking for a link to Nautilus Subversion plugin, and I find out it's now called [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org).)

There's also a [KDE plugin](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de) that works with the KDE browser too. (Although I now am told that RabbitVCS will also work with KDE as well as a Finder plugin for Mac OS X.)

If you just want a web-based Subversion browser, so your users don't even have to install Subversion, I highly recommend [Sventon](http://sventon.org). It works in the base Tomcat server. Allows you to see the history, do diffs, and view files.

Comment: Okay, finally I decided that RabbitVCS it the best (and the only) option. If there were better alternatives, somebody would point me to them, right?:) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think rapidsvn may be your best option.