# Setting up git-svn without access to the SVN server

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I currently cannot connect to the SVN server of the company.
Therefore I'd like to use git-svn to be able to make local commits and later on push them into SVN when I recover access to the SVN server.

**My question is:** is it possible to setup git-svn on my local copy of the repository (available on my machine), without having to re-checkout fresh sources from the SVN server? (since I don't have access to this server right now).

Answer (score 0):

"Setting up git-svn" doesn't mean much if you're not connected to the SVN server.

git-svn exists to allow you to push git commits as SVN commits. So, to "set it up" in the manner you're talking about... you just make git commits. Those commits won't be somehow invalid just because they were made without talking to Subversion.

Later, when you get access to the SVN server, you can rebase those commits and then `git svn dcommit` to send them up to SVN.

Comment: This is an actual explanation to the answer of why not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083679/can-i-import-from-svn-to-git-without-connecting-to-a-remote-server