# Is it possible to convert an SVN branch into a new GIT repo?

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

Our organization never used Trunk, and simply created new SVN branches for each version.  Is it possible to simply select the most recent branch, and create a new Git repo of that branch (with history)?

Comment: `git svn init` has plenty of configuration options.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I've no idea why this was closed as "off-topic". It's a rather basic question, but it's about using Git and SVN, and thus totally on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply choose to clone only one branch from the SVN repo:

```
git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/mostRecentBranch
```

This will create a git repo with a single branch, which represents the history of "mostRecentBranch" from the SVN repo.

`git svn` will try to also include history from before the branch's creation (i.e. the history of the branch that "mostRecentBranch" was copied/created from). However, this may not work if the branch was not created properly in SVN (i.e. if it was not created using "svn copy").

Comment: Defends my question AND provides the correct answer.  Awesome!

Comment: is there any way to start this at a particular revision? We have a large SVN repo with 71000 commits and my project starts at around r50000, so I'd like to skip the first 50000 commits.

Comment: @JasonS: See [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository).