# Converting a local svn repo dump to git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, svn2git

I searched related questions but I couldn't find anything matching my specific situation: I have some old repository archives from an SVN server that was taken down years ago. They're tarballs of the original repository structure on the server. What I want to do is convert them to git repositories as a basis for future work/reviving the projects. I've already read several tutorials about the conversion process, and I think I can figure out the authors conversion, branches mapping, etc., but they all assume you have an SVN server and a url for the repository. Do I need to install and setup and SVN server to do this conversion, or is there some way I can point either `git clone` or `svn2git` (or another tool) at the repo dump I have?

Comment: Standard edition of VisualSVN Server is free, so there's plan B.

Comment: I think installing the original SVN server would be a good bit easier than that..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

install subversion locally in order to import your dump, then with git-svn package.

You can use `git svn clone file:///path/to/svn/repo /path/to/empty/dir`

Comment: I already found this experimenting last night and got it working, but this is the correct answer. Thanks and +1/accepted! And welcome to SO. :-)

Answer (score 10):

**Retrieve a list of all Subversion committers**:

`svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt`

**Clone the Subversion repository using git-svn**:

`git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp`

**Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore**:

```
cd ~/temp
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore.'
```

**Push repository to a bare git repository**:

```
git init --bare ~/new-bare.git
cd ~/new-bare.git
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk
```

Then push the temp repository to the new bare repository.

```
cd ~/temp
git remote add bare ~/new-bare.git
git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*'
git push bare
```

**Rename “trunk” branch to “master”**:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git branch -m trunk master
```

**Clean up branches and tags**:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
  git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
  git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

Reference: http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

Comment: Also see [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository) which describes how to selectively clone svn to git.

Answer (score 2):

1. All (?) svn -> git converters require live Subversion repository,
2. Tree-copy of repository is not a dump, it's usual file-level backup.

You have:

1. Install and configure any Subversion server (if your converter can't handle `file:///` protocol for SVN, otherwise it's not needed - just unpack tarball(s) and check repo with svn client)
2. Read about git-svn
3. Use git-svn

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the dump file in your severs:

   ```
   svnadmin dump "repopath or url" > import.bkp

   git svn clone "back"
   ```
2. Go to the clone path and then open git bash and 
   run these commands:

   ```
   git svn show-ignore > .gitignore

   git add .gitignore

   git commit -m "with message"

   git check in "git url"
   ```

Comment: Can you elaborate what `git svn clone "back"` does?  I'm not understanding how svnadmin dump and this command relate to one another?  Are you just taking a backup of the svn repository prior to using git svn clone, in case you screw something up?

Answer (score 0):

The [`reposurgeon`](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/reposurgeon/) tool supports direct (and extremely fast) conversion of SVN dump files to Git repositories.