# svn2git or git svn import

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm about to migrate my SVN repo to GIT.
I'm going to use svn2git which uses the git-svn.

Is there any way the process modifies the SVN repo? Since obviously this is very sensitive to change, I want to be sure that the original SVN will not be affected in any way.

Comment: Why would you not simply use `git svn clone <svn url>` to obtain a complete git history of your existing svn respository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-svn` *can* commit changes back to svn with `git svn dcommit`, `git svn branch` or `git svn tag` commands, but it doesn't do so unless you explicitly tell it to. `svn2git` only calls [`git svn init` and `git svn fetch`](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/blob/master/lib/svn2git/migration.rb), so it won't modify anything in the original repository.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used svn2git but I have just done `git svn clone <URI to the svn repo>` and it has worked perfectly fine for me. No issues at all.

Also see here: [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository) and here: [8.2 Git and Other Systems - Migrating to Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)