# Import svn repo to git WITHOUT history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I need to import svn repo (trunk, branches, tags) to new empty git repo WITHOUT history.
Svn history is very large, because many branches and tags exist.

Svn's trunk must get into git's master. Svn's branches must get into git's branches. And svn's tags must get into git's tags. All without history.

This command will import with history:

```
git svn clone http://server.ru/myrepo/ --stdlayout --preserve-empty-dirs .
```

Do branches and tags import by hands (checkout each from svn and commit to git) is too laborious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Read [git-svn man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) *carefully*, pay attention to `-r` option and use `-r HEAD` on clone

Answer (score 1):

Advised `-r HEAD` seems to be getting the latest trunk revision only, but ignores branches and tags. Moreover, in my test it failed the execution of git-svn clone when last commit to repository was not to trunk.

What you could try is fetching trunk, branches and tags individually. First init empty git-svn repository:

`git svn init http://server.ru/myrepo/ --stdlayout .`

Then for each of trunk, tags, branches find their latest svn revision and do git-svn-fetch:

`git svn fetch -r <svn revision>`

To avoid manual labor, you could probably create a simple script that would parse the output of the `svn ls -v <svn_path>/branches` or `svn ls --xml <svn_path>/tags`.

Alternatively, if you already have git-svn-imported repository but want to strip the history, you could do for each branch/trunk: `git checkout --orphan <branch> && git commit -m "as imported from svn"` - that will produce a bunch of detached branches that you can further push to a new "clean" git repository.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Mykola!
But `git svn fetch -r <last_svn_revision>` fetches nothing. Should I specify revision interval? It is equal to full history clone.

Comment: I am not sure why git-svn-fetch by last svn revision doesn't work to you. Could possibly be combination of versions svn server/client/git-svn. If revisions work to you instead, you could ask for very shallow history: `git svn fetch -r <last_svn_revision-1>:<last_svn_revision> or so.

Comment: @MykolaGurov: in the git svn init command, do we provide a url for the trunk, for the branches, or the root url which contains both trunk and branches? For example, http://server/myrepo contains both trunk and branches folder, so are we to provide http://server/myrepo, http://server/myrepo/trunk or http://server/myrepo/branches//***? in case of git svn init?

Comment: @WaqasShah did you read https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_basic_examples ?