# Incremental Migration from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone, svnsync

Consider my below scenario :

Suppose my svn repository contains *100 revisions*, which has been migrated to Git Repository (So my Git contains the 100 revisions).

Now my svn repository got updated, say with 5 more revisions hence it has *105 revisions*. **How do i migrate only the revisions 101 t0 105 to my GIT repository?**

The main challenges I have :

1. I dont want to sync both SVN and Git.(SVN will be decommisioned soon)
2. I need to migrate the Revisions with its history.

I tried following up with these links which dont help me,(fyi)

1. Using [svnsync](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/01/moving-confluence-from-subversion-to-git/)
2. USing [git svn clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository)

Comment: Whats wrong with the anders in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository ? They don't work? or?

Comment: I wish to migrate to the existing Git repository and i should bring History for me.

Comment: That part was pretty clear, but why dont the linked questions help you? especially the 2nd

Comment: It is not bringing revisions from 101 to 105, as i mentioned I need only the latest revisions to get it updated to the migrated Git repository.

Comment: You can specify the revisiions you want to clone

Comment: I had specified the revision number.

Comment: That may be because 101 to 105 occurred somewhere other than trunk.  You need to make sure you tell git-svn how you wanted Subversion mapped into Git.  There's a `--stdlayout` option, but if that doesn't work for you, then you should specify it manually.  Not all commits will appears as history for the *master* branch--some commits may have just been for tags, or for other branches.  Those commits will appear in their respective places within the Git repo when you have them mapped correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use git-svn. When you do initial clone `git svn clone ...` you will get the first 100 revisions. Later you do `git svn fetch` which would fetch the newly appeared 5 revisions.

All 105 revisions will be present in a correct order thus the history will be preserved.

Update:

If you wish to avoid getting first 100 revisions, do git svn init with fetch initially:

```
git svn init ...
git svn fetch -r <svn revision you want to start from>
```

Comment: Mykola it wont bring HISTORY.

Comment: Saby, it WILL bring HISTORY :)

Comment: How you are saying by doing **git svn clone** it ll bring only the first 100 revisions? @Mykola When I did  **git svn clone**  brought 105 revisions.

Comment: Saby, if you want to skip the earlier revisions and keep only the last 5 revisions, you may use `-r/--revision` option together with the initial [git svn fetch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

Comment: Yeah I understood. But now I am talking  about the first step which you had mentioned about git svn clone.

Comment: Yes I did git svn fetch, how can I push it now to the Git repository.

Comment: after successful `git svn fetch` you should get svn revisions fetched to your git-svn repository.

Comment: Thanks Mykola, Its working fine. But I am unable to push it to server.

Comment: You may describe your next problem in a new question

Comment: Hi All, I have exactly the same problem. But when I do git svn fetch only the remote ref is getting updated not the local branch I have created for each ref