# Merging selective SVN revisions from a SVN branch into GIt Branch

Tags: git, git-svn

We have moved onto GIT about 2 weeks ago and we locked down the SVN check in to the svn trunk. Our main production release is still on a SVN release branch - i have made quite a few bug fixes on this svn branch and now i want to merge a selective range of revision from the svn branch onto the GIT Master branch.

I read that git svn can do this job, but i am unable to get it to work. Is there any plugin from eclipse that allows me to do this easily or if not, can you let me know what syntax it is exactly to do this please?

so far,

I found this post, which is closest to what i want to do do. It only talks about how to clone the revisions that i want to merge.

[How to git-svn clone the last n revisions from a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository)

but it doesnt seem to explain how do i actually merge it back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to get all of your svn checkins into any git branch you can cherry-pick the once you want into any other git branch.

I always like to get as much as possible into git, in your case to as quick as possible be able to stop using svn entirely.

Comment: So are you saying, i should clone those revisions i want, and check it into some feature branch. Then just use stash and merge the feature branch into master. is that right?

Comment: I don't think stash has any place here, when you have all your svn commits on some branch you'll cherry-pick those you want into master.