# Chaining SVN Repositories

Tags: svn, git-svn

I have an SVN repository that is created for me every year at the same time as an administrative process that is out of my control (mostly, though I could ask for changes). I would like to take the old repo from the prior year and make the new repo's history pick up where the old one left off. Is there a way to replay the changes in an old repo in a new repo? If the revision numbers change, I don't care. I just want the history. Even something like using `git svn` if it can be hacked to make this happen might be helpful. Like pulling from the old repo then pushing to the new repo.

I'd like an answer ideally that assumes I have no administrative control over the SVN server, but assumes that I have a brand new untouched SVN repo.

The workaround right now is just to copy the files over and add them to the new repo, and then the history is lost, so I'm trying to avoid that loss of history.

Comment: Why don't you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository Git svn can also help https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Answer (score 2):

> an answer ideally that assumes I have no administrative control over the SVN server

Answer will be **NO**. In order to transfer old history to the new repo you have to have

- Possibility to perform `svnadmin load` on server

or

- Edit one or repository-hooks (again - locally) in order to perform `svnrdump load`